# I am trying to extract data from database in string

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```java
   @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflate layout (row_user.xml)
        //viewGroup symbol cant be found, in the tutorial below he doesnt have it anywhere
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_users, viewGroup, false);


        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
        //get data
      

        String userImage = usersList.get(i).getImage();
//i appears red for some reason, symbol not //found
        String userName = usersList.get(i).getPseudonym();
       String userPractic = usersList.get(i).getPractic();
        String userType = usersList.get(i).getType();
```

I've been following this tutorial until now, he doesn't have any problem. It is so weird that he is able to do that without problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRGZchw5z7s

Also the "dataSnapshot" appears red, I guess it has to be changed to "snapshot"

```java
 @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                usersList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ModelUsers modelUser = ds.getValue(ModelUsers.class);
                    //get all users except
                    if (!modelUser.getUid().equals(fUser.getUid())) {
                        usersList.add(modelUser);
                    }
                    adapterUsers = new AdapterUsers(getActivity(), usersList);
                    //set adapter to recycler view
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);
                }
            }
```

I get this in logcat:

> 2020-12-17 20:10:32.300 13692-13692/com.android.yoganetworks
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for email found on class
> com.android.yoganetwork.ModelUsers 2020-12-17 20:10:32.300
> 13692-13692/com.android.yoganetworks W/ClassMapper: No setter/field
> for realname found on class com.android.yoganetwork.ModelUsers
> 2020-12-17 20:10:32.305 13692-13692/com.android.yoganetworks
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for name found on class
> com.android.yoganetwork.ModelUsers 2020-12-17 20:10:32.305
> 13692-13692/com.android.yoganetworks W/ClassMapper: No setter/field
> for profileStatus found on class com.android.yoganetwork.ModelUsers
> 2020-12-17 20:10:32.305 13692-13692/com.android.yoganetworks
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for email found on class
> com.android.yoganetwork.ModelUsers 2020-12-17 20:10:32.305
> 13692-13692/com.android.yoganetworks W/ClassMapper: No setter/field
> for realname found on class com.android.yoganetwork.ModelUsers
> 2020-12-17 20:10:32.305 13692-13692/com.android.yoganetworks
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for profileStatus found on class
> com.android.yoganetwork.ModelUsers 2020-12-17 20:10:32.305
> 13692-13692/com.android.yoganetworks W/ClassMapper: No setter/field
> for email found on class com.android.yoganetwork.ModelUsers 2020-12-17
> 20:10:32.305 13692-13692/com.android.yoganetworks W/ClassMapper: No
> setter/field for realname found on class
> com.android.yoganetwork.ModelUsers
> Blockquote

Here is my ModelUsers

```
package com.android.yoganetwork;

public class ModelUsers {

//use same name as in firebase database
String pseudonym, practic, type, diet, image, cover, uid;


public ModelUsers() {

}

public ModelUsers(String pseudonym, String practic, String type, String diet, String image, String cover, String uid) {
    this.pseudonym = pseudonym;
    this.practic = practic;
    this.type = type;
    this.diet = diet;
    this.image = image;
    this.cover = cover;
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getPseudonym() {
    return pseudonym;
}

public void setPseudonym(String pseudonym) {
    this.pseudonym = pseudonym;
}

public String getPractic() {
    return practic;
}

public void setPractic(String practic) {
    this.practic = practic;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getDiet() {
    return diet;
}

public void setDiet(String diet) {
    this.diet = diet;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getCover() {
    return cover;
}

public void setCover(String cover) {
    this.cover = cover;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
```

}

```
And JSON of my database

    {
  "Users" : {
    "Az7EiIgHSTUobarMFdncbv" : {
      "cover" : "",
      "diet" : "veggies",
      "email" : "ejejdjdjd@fkfkf.dfg",
      "image" : "",
      "practic" : "",
      "pseudonym" : "",
      "realname" : "",
      "type" : "",
      "uid" : "Az7EiIgHSTURtJrMFdncbv"
    },
    "NkxX9tzcXsOTn0LeLVuPQfzCGjG2" : {
      "cover" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/database-de88e.appspot.com/o/Users_Profile_Cover_Imgs%2Fcover_NkxX9tzcXsOTn0LeLfzCGjG2?alt=media&token=5f46be85-d333-4ef6-b947-70f5f23a1",
      "diet" : "Vegetariano",
      "email" : "test@gmail.com",
      "image" : "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/silhouette-palm-trees-sunset-vintage-600w-415974139.jpg",
      "name" : "ACACACAAAAA",
      "practic" : "Yoga Kundalini",
      "profileStatus" : "PRACTICA",
      "pseudonym" : "asdasdasda",
      "realname" : "Sasha",
      "type" : "Instructor",
      "uid" : "NkxX9tzcXsOThfgh5LVuPQfzCGjG2"
    },
    "wDP3jpUoXcdjdsgge4CVDAMFThiCb2" : {
      "cover" : "",
      "diet" : "",
      "email" : "fsdgshe@gmail.com",
      "image" : "",
      "practic" : "",
      "profileStatus" : "ffsdhhh",
      "pseudonym" : "",
      "realname" : "asdasd",
      "type" : "",
      "uid" : "wDP3jpUoXcdj5ffCCVDAMFThiCb2"
    }
  }
}


Only a couple users appear on the users fragment. I hope you can help me because I'm really stuck
```

Comment: It looks like your `ModelUsers` is missing some properties for fields that you have in your JSON. If you [search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+No+setter%2Ffield+for+found+on+class) you'll get some questions where people have dealt with this message before. If you can't fix it by following the same solutions, we'll have to see the JSON you're loading and the `ModelUsers` class.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also add the content of your `ModelUsers` class.

Comment: Alrighty, done.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to:
Declare in public class    `private Object ViewGroup;` then  `View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_users, (android.view.ViewGroup) ViewGroup, false);`
In strings instead of "i" index, put position: `String userImage = usersList.get(position).getImage();`
And for the last one, instead of "dataSnapshot" in  `for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren())`, put only "snapshot":  `for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren())`